# Sort products in category by stock quatity or stock availabilty

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sorting

I show out of stock items on my website and they are all over the place but I dont want to get rid of them.

I want to sort the category so that products that are out of stock appear last, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

i use this module [Rayfox Catalog](https://github.com/kirchbergerknorr/Rayfox_Catalog), work fine for me. 
was try and test many solutions, but this IMHO best one.

in case of some conflicts possible in Models `catalog/layer` or `catalogsearch/layer` (this often used by other modules/themes for catalog sorting), you can try more simple module, with only one `Observer` - method used, without `layer` rewrites:
[Magento-StockSort](https://github.com/ooworx/magento-stocksort) (was **not** tested myself)

Comment: Im using a similar module but as im using ajax it randomly aranges products so i may see a product on page two that was on page one. Would you know of it works. I can test it tomorrow :) thanks

Comment: was add more simple module link, when I have this task in past, was noticed that very dependent how many other modules/themes want rewrite this `layers` and may provide conflict with Rayfox_Catalog module